# Local fonts vs online fonts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization

In terms of optimization and fast render of a static website, i know many of you have this doubt too.

**Which way its better to use?**

1. Local fonts in the project
2. Get online fonts from cdn?

**NOTE: Feel free to add more best practices to the others assets, images,audio,videos**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to other assets, it mostly depends on how many users would you expect to be using them, for example:

Assets such as jquery files, bootstrap files, and other libraries that are being used by many other websites and probably or definitely have been cached in the user's browser, it is best to use a **CDN** since it would reduce page load time.

But for others such as videos, images that are only being provided by your site, you can just supply them to the user locally, since you wouldn't expect the user to actually have them cached in their browser, since the content is native to your site

Answer (score 2):

Online fonts, if you know where to look, can be very appealing. This depends on your tech stack. For instance, if you use Bootstrap, I can recommend Font Awesome to consider. Get into the habit of integrating fonts from third-party libraries, it'll make you more flexible.

If the font is unimportant in your project, though, don't overthink it. Use a local font

Comment: Plesase, be more specific in the why, so everyone can clear their minds